# Can we identify ARIMA model without looking at ACF and PACF plot?

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation, partial-correlation, automatic-algorithms

Can we identify ARIMA($p,d,q$) model without looking at the ACF and PACF plots?
I am trying to write a generalized R programme for fitting time series models.

We may find out the orders $p$, $d$ and $q$ from the ACF and PACF plots, but I want to know how to identify them from the *numerical values* of the ACF and PACF.

Comment: You can use any number of criteria to choose the model... but there are already R programs for choosing the order of ARIMA.

Comment: No need for re-designing the wheel, it already exists in R, check `auto.arima` function in `forecast` library, cf. https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7

Comment: Thanks Tim for your response, I tried this function in forecast package But auto.arima not gives the exact order of our data which is used for forecast. From ACF and PACF plot i found the ARIMA order and is used for future forecasting.But i want to know to find ARIMA order  through programmatically in R.

Answer (score 4):

The common approach is to choose the model that minimizes the [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion), the [BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) or a modified version of these criteria.

Section 3 in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v027.i03) $^{[1]}$ mentions some software tools that implement automatic detection procedures for choosing an ARIMA model. You may find more details in the documentation or reference papers.

[1] Rob J. Hyndman, Yeasmin Khandakar (2008).
Automatic Time Series Forecasting: The forecast Package for R.
*Journal of Statistical Software*. DOI: [10.18637/jss.v027.i03](http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v027.i03).

Comment: we are plotting acf and pacf plot in r using acf and pacf function and it generate plot to identified that our data is stationary or not and also used for finding ARIMA order.but i want to generalise my code using acf and pacf value .

Comment: this is the example :-> acf<-acf(ATM_RC052009_CHAROLI_TS)
> 
> acf

Autocorrelations of series ‘ATM_RC052009_CHAROLI_TS’, by lag

0.00000 0.00274 0.00548 0.00822 0.01096 0.01370 0.01644 0.01918 0.02192 0.02466 0.02740 0.03014 0.03288 0.03562 0.03836 0.04110 0.04384 0.04658 0.04932 0.05205 
  1.000   0.438   0.313   0.222   0.179   0.065   0.052   0.008   0.111  -0.016  -0.005  -0.081  -0.099  -0.098  -0.200  -0.193  -0.089  -0.111  -0.107  -0.103 
0.05479 0.05753 
 -0.100  -0.084

Comment: @Shahnawaz I think it is easier to implement a model selection based on the AIC or BIC rather than on the ACF and PACF.
I don't know a reasonable design of a procedure that chooses the model looking at the values of the ACF and PACF; I don't think it is the right approach anyway.

Comment: I would recommend you to read the papers and code of the references I mentioned. It can be an interesting pedagogical exercise where you may come up with some ideas and try some variations or alternatives to the common approach.

Comment: Thanks javlacalle,Now i got it and it's easier to implement and choosing model based on minimum AIC and BIC value.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't identify the model just from the ACF and PACF.  You need to also consider looking at outliers, changes in level/trend/seasonality/parameters/variance.  If you assume that these don't exist and try and force a model to the data you are prone to model specification bias.

Tsay, R.S. (1986). "Time Series Model Specification in the Presence of Outliers," Journal of the American Statistical Society, Vol. 81, pp. 132-141.

http://www.orms-today.org/orms-6-08/survey.html

http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/products/autobox/text-references

Comment: ok i will chk and read that paper and let u know

Comment: You might need to also read these https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_test ww.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf www.jstor.org/stable/1391308                                  No link for the change in trend or seasonality as that is proprietary to Autobox.